# Is there a way to establish a connection between a Firebird database and a React-Native application?

Tags: react-native, firebird

Our project relies on displaying data from a Firebird database on a React-Native application.

If I import the Firebird library we get the error:

> "Module 'net' does not exist in the Haste module map"

Following the given instructions doesn't change anything.

Typing so much as this is enough to cause the error:

```
var Firebird = require('node-firebird');
```

We tried working with [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-firebird) npm package.

My colleague spoke to an online React-Native teacher and it seems both frameworks are indeed incompatible. If possible, I'd hope to get more clear input on the matter, and if there exists any alternatives, I'd be glad to hear them.

Comment: Why do you want to directly connect your application to fetch data from your DB? Develop a backend application like using node which can surely use `node-firebird` to fetch data from your DB and serve that to your application using REST Apis and that's how applications are served data ideally.

Comment: As previous commentator said better develop separate back-end and connect your front part to it. As for driver look for https://github.com/asfernandes/node-firebird-drivers as it is maintained actively.